# Yii2 mail in not sending on portal.azure.com

Tags: yii2, azure-web-app-service, yii2-advanced-app

I have migrate a Yii2 website from Apache server to portal.azure.com windows server. I have checked that mail is not sending on windows server.
Do anyone have any idea, what I have missed in this.

Thanks

Comment: You should post your config and troubleshooting steps you have taken in attempt to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I have followed the following steps:-
1. Uploaded the code to bit-bucket.
2. Created a sync between Azure and bit-bucket.
3. Tried to replace mail server with default Yii2. Also tried to comment it.

After so many tries, I checked that it need domain email id, password, host name and port to configure.

Then I have setup the send-grid package to azure and created account on send-grid. 

Now the mail are working through send-grid.

Answer (score 2):

I have used send-grid(https://sendgrid.com/) to setup mail system in Yii2 on portal.azure.com. It should be like below:-

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
            'username' => 'azure_************@azure.com',
            'password' => '***********',
            'port' => '25',
            //'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
],
```